# Using serilog in a class library referenced by other projects

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a solution containing multiple .NET Core API and windows services. How can I integrate Serilog in such a way that I will not be required to make changes at several different places for adding a column or changing some property?

I'm thinking of adding Serilog in a common library and use that custom library in all other projects however how to invoke starting point of the serilog as we see in below code in Program.cs, any code reference will help.

```
 .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Debug()
                            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.File(path: Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Logs", "log.txt"),
                                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                                retainedFileCountLimit: 20,
                                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                                fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000
                                )
                            .WriteTo.Console();
                })
```

================ Updated ===================

```
For windows service, I have the code in common library.
public class LogManager : ILogManager
    {
       public LogManager()
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                             .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                             //  .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug, OutputTemplate, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
                             .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\Users\hnq6ww\Documents\Important\logs.txt",
                                                        LogEventLevel.Verbose,
                                                        // OutputTemplate,
                                                        retainedFileCountLimit: (int?)RollingInterval.Day,
                                                        buffered: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000)
                             .CreateLogger();
            }
}
```

In Program.cs

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ILogManager log = new LogManager();
            log.WriteLog(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information, "Testing");
        }
```

Comment: You can create an extension method that does this, in your class library and use that extension method in your API projects.

Comment: @honey_ramgarhia Sorry I'm not sure how to do that, could you please give me an example.

Answer (score 8):

In your common library you can create an extension method that will inject Serilog into your multiple .NET Web API projects

So you can have something like this in your common class lib

```
public static class SerilogDi
    {
        public static IHostBuilder InjectSerilog(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        {
            hostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Debug()
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .WriteTo.File(path: Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Logs", "log.txt"),
                            rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                            retainedFileCountLimit: 20,
                            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                            fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000
                            )
                        .WriteTo.Console();
            });

            return hostBuilder;
        }
    }
```

and then you can add project reference of this project into your .NET Web API projects and inject Serilog in them, something like this

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .InjectSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Also, you can make `InjectSerilog()` parameterized to further configure it on per project basis.

**UPDATE**
Ok according to your update I think you only want to configuration to be common. So what you can do is create a static method in your common library which return a configured logger.

```
public static class MySerilog
    {
        public static Logger GetInstance()
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
                             .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                             //  All my settings here
                             .CreateLogger();
        }
    }
```

and then in your other projects you can use this instance

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = MySerilog.GetInstance();
}
```

And in your `CreateHostBuilder` method you can simply do

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

This will work for both types of your project and you can make `GetInstance()` parameterized as well!

You can further refer here
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore

Comment: thanks ... how to achieve the same if the application is a windows service. I have added the code under "Updated" section, could you please have a look and help me how to add extension over there, probably a common code for web/windows service application

Comment: That didn't help me, I feel I got misdirected. I don't want the configuration to be common, the configuration will be sent by each application, I don't want to install serilog and encrihers in each application so I need a common solution(library) so library will take care of pushing logs.

Comment: If someone is looking to do this in .NET 6 where we see `WebApplicationBuilder`, you can do this by: `builder.Host.InjectSerilog();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move logging logic into separate library, then you need to do the following steps.

The first step is to create logic of logging in your class library:

```
public interface ILoggerService
{
    void Info(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information info, Message message );
}

public class LoggerService : ILoggerService
{   
    public void Write(LogEventLevel level, Message message) =>
        Serilog.Log.Write(serilogEvents[level], JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
        
}
```

Then you need to create an extension method in your class library to register your service in other projects:

```
public static class LoggingServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterMyLogger(this IServiceCollection services, 
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom
            .Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerService, LoggerService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

If your are going to use this library in ASP.NET Core MVC or Web API, then just register your library:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigBaseServiceSettings<AppSettings>(Configuration);
    services.RegisterMyLogger(Configuration);
}
```

Do not forget to install the following dependencies through NuGet in your class library:

```
Serilog 
Serilog.Settings.Configuration
```

And other libraries if you want:

```
Serilog.Sinks.Console
Serilog.Sinks.Http
Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just a usabillity recommendation based on the answer from honey_ramgarhia

I wraped the serilog usage in a common helper library. This way only the main program (Service, Webapp, whatever) and the common library needs to reference the serilog nuget package.

```
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static Logger GetInstance()
    {
        return new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(GetLogFilePath())
                .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void LogText(string text)
    {
        Log.Information(text);
    }

    public static void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex.Message + ";" + ex.InnerException + "Stacktrace:" + ex.StackTrace, Encoding.Default);
    }

    public static void End()
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }    

}
```